# Inserting a link in an image on a Cloud Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I have to put a link in a Cloud Page using AMPscript so that when you click on a certain image you are redirected to that link. To do so, I use RequestParameter to get a specific parameter from the URL. Then I use RetrieveSalesforceObjects, Row and Field to get the link associated to the parameter taken from the URL. I put the link in a variable (let's say @link) and then use the code `%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%`in the href HTML tag of the image. Is there any error in the AMPscript?

Here is the rest of my code:

```
%%[
var @IdAnn, @rs, @row, @link 
set @IdAnn = RequestParameter('IdAnnuncio') 
set @rs = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Opportunity","Link_Autologin_primafila__c","Id","=",@IdAnn) 
set @row = Row(@rs,1) 
set @link = FIELD(@row,'Link_Autologin_primafila__c') 
]%%
```

Comment: It's hard to tell if there is an error from the information provided. Can you please provide the your whole ampscript code? are you getting a 500 error?

Comment: This is the code I'm using in the Cloud Page
`%%[
var @IdAnn, @rs, @row, @link 
set @IdAnn = RequestParameter('IdAnnuncio') 
set @rs = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Opportunity","Link_Autologin_primafila__c","Id","=",@IdAnn) 
set @row = Row(@rs,1) 
set @link = FIELD(@row,'Link_Autologin_primafila__c') 
]%%`
Yes, I get an Error 500

Comment: Try printing the value on `@link` on the cloud page. A 500 error indicates an error with server-side logic eg malformed ampscript.

Comment: try print the value with `%%=v(@link)=%%`

Comment: I still get a 500 error.

Comment: How are you passing IdAnnuncio to the page? Can you comment out all the lines after set @IdAnn = RequestParameter('IdAnnuncio') and try printing %%=v(@IdAnn)==%% on the page?

Comment: I pass IdAnnuncio from the email using URLencode and Concat. I tried the steps you suggested and it works, I can print @IdAnn on the page.

Comment: Now it works; maybe it depends on the fact that I added AccountId and Id in the RetrieveSalesforceObjects function.